# javascript show sqlite parameters values

Tags: javascript, sqlite, parameters, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova sqlite plugin. I am having some trouble with my query getting the results I expect. If I hard code the parameter values in my query works as I expect it to so my query is fine. I need to see what the values are of my parameters once they are passed to my sql query. I am not sure how to get the values of my parameter once they are inside the actual query. I want to make sure the query is getting the values properly.

here is my relevant code

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM empvalues WHERE (amount * ?   + salary  * ?  * (sales * ? + years * ?) > ?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [var_amount,var_salary,var_totalsales,var_years,var_totalvalue]).then(function(res)...
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether your parameters end up correctly in SQL, use a query that just returns the parameters' values, and check the result:

```
execute(db, "SELECT ? AS amount, ? AS salary", [var_amount, var_salary])
```

Comment: that did it. Thanks. Seems like my parameters are being passed. Perhaps something else is the issue. So odd since when I manually put in the values it works fine. If I use parameters I get no results.